# Proving an Inequality Involving the Summation of Modulo Functions

Tags: inequality, summation

I have a function, $c(n)$, so that $$c(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n n \bmod i$$ I also have the function $f(n)$ and $g(n)$, so $$f(n)=\left(c\left(n-1\right)+n-1\right)-c\left(n\right)+n$$ and $$g(n)=e^{\gamma}n\ln\ln n$$ with $\gamma$ being the Euler-Mascheroni constant. Is it possible to prove that for large enough $n$, $f(n)<g(n)$?

Comment: This might help: $ c(n)=2n-1- (\sum_{d|n} d ) $   ?

Comment: @PratikJadhav How does that help?

Comment: If Pratik's formula is correct, then it relates your $c(n)$ to the reasonably-well-understood sum-of-divisors function, $\sigma(n)$. In particular, there's the sharp lower bound $\sigma(n)\ge n+1$, and there are upper bounds in the literature. Incidentally, $c(n)$ is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A004125 with formulas and links to the literature.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Incidentally, I got $c(n)$ by trying to simplify $\sigma(n)$.