# Formula to Find $k$ to put $\frac nm$ in between a Range

Tags: inequality, integers

I have a function $$f(n,m)=-\frac {2n}m+1+2k$$ where $n$ and $m$ are both positive integers. Is there a way to find the positive integer value $k$ that would put $-1 \leq f(n,m) \leq 1$ for an $n$ and $m$ (without using $\mathbb{floor}$, $\mathbb{ceil}$, or $\mathbb{mod}$)?

Comment: I don't see how. Let's say $m=100$. Then for $n=0$ you get $k=0$. But you would get the same answer if $n=1$ or $2$ or any number up to $n=50$. So $k$ would be a sum of step functions of constant relative displacements, which is something like $\textrm{floor}$

Comment: You could find a formula for $k$ using floor and/or ceiling, and then replace the functions you don't want with their Fourier expansions.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Interestingly enough, the problem I had arose from trying to find an algebraic equation for $\bmod$

Comment: What would be the advantage in having an algebraic equation for mod?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Please look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3617572/proving-an-inequality-involving-the-summation-of-modulo-functions and this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3613414/simplification-of-the-sum-of-modulo-functions